# AudioTrack no sound with tone generation

Tags: android, byte, media, wav, pcm

I'm trying to get Android's AudioTrack play a squarewave with the following code

```
public Synthesizer() {
    bufferSize = android.media.AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    player = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

}

public void writeSamples(byte[] samples) {
    fillBuffer(samples);
    player.write(buffer, 0, samples.length);
}

private void putBuffer(byte[] samples) {
    if (buffer.length < samples.length)
        buffer = new byte[samples.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++)
        buffer[i] = samples[i];
```

Even samples will be negative, the others will be positive, to get a square wave:

```
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            int frequency = 44100;
            byte[] sample = new byte[frequency];
            for (int i = 0; i < frequency; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    sample[i] = Byte.MAX_VALUE;
                }

                else {
                    sample[i] = Byte.MIN_VALUE;

                }
            }
            squareSynth.writeSamples(sample);
```

Unfortunately I get no sound at all, i've checked my volume but couldn't even get static or some crackle. I find this very strange. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried running `player.play()` ?